# I cant read the result from the Oraclize query but i can call it successfully

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, truffle, oraclize

I create another function in solidity to return the result also there (getGameNumbers) but can I add it to oraclizeCall function [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONc2S.jpg)

```
  async WinningNumbers ()  {
  const {accounts, contract}=this.state;

  this.state.contract.methods.GenerateGameNumbers().send({from: accounts[0],gas:5000000, fromBlock: 'latest', toBlock: 'latest'+1},(err,results) =>{

    if(results !=null){
      this.setState({
        winNum: (results)

      })
    }
  })
}
```

I get the transaction hash in the console instead of the result

Comment: i think what you are searching for is in this issue : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status

Comment: @ChamsddinBouzaine maybe now it prints the transaction hash on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because I was using oraclize I should call the callback function instead of the one who generate the numbers but as I am using enums I created different functions to get the results and call those